# The function of Prepositional Phrase in a sentence

Tags: phrases, prepositions

I wish to know the function of the prepositional phrase (adverbial?) that modifies the intransitive verb in the following sentence. "I THINK OF HIM"

Comment: The PP is not a modifier but a **complement** of "think".

Comment: 'Of him' seems to function as complement. It also answers 'What do I think?'